# Error with mx:Remoteobject

Tags: apache-flex

I'm building a Flex/PHP application. I have put some charts on my page and I want them to be getting data from a database.

Looking at mx:RemoteObject, it seems as if I need to have a query to select the records (in PHP code) and call that method. Nothing difficult (I've posted links on how to do this below), but this line keeps throwing an error:

```
                    <mx:RemoteObject showBusyCursor="true" source="ChartPersistance" result="result(event)" fault="fault(event)">
```

I have the result and fault functions in my code as a scope of private. What is wrong with the above line?

http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/flex_remoteobject/

http://www.cftips.net/post.cfm/flex-line-chart-using-cfc-flash-remoting

What exactly am I doing wrong? The source seems to be the class file (not in the directory though).

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you see? 
By the way, it may be simply missing from the pasted code, but the RemoteObject tag should be closed `<mx:RemoteObject .... />` if you don't have any inner tag.